# "KeyError: 'word'" or "NameError: <name of dictionary>" depending on how I change my code

Tags: python

This dictionary initialization yields "NameError: statearray is not defined."

```
for state in mystates:

    statearray[state.abbrev()]={}

    statearray[state.abbrev()]['count'] = 0
    statearray[state.abbrev()]['total score'] = 0
    statearray[state.abbrev()]['avg'] = statearray[state.abbrev()]['count']/statearray[state.abbrev()]['total score'
```

This dictionary initialization yields "KeyError: 'WA'" for the state of Wyoming.

```
for state in mystates:

    statearray={}

    statearray[state.abbrev()]['count'] = 0
    statearray[state.abbrev()]['total score'] = 0
    statearray[state.abbrev()]['avg'] = statearray[state.abbrev()]['count']/statearray[state.abbrev()]['total score'
```

I need to initialize all 50 states with this base values but I either get an error for mentioning a key that hasn't been entered yet, or get an error for using a dictionary that doesn't exist yet. Is there an easy fix to this?

Comment: put the dict definition `statearray={}` outside the `for` loop or it is set bak to empty at each step

Comment: what is the difference between `state.abbrev` and `state.abbrev()`?

Comment: I moved the array outside of the forloop, and am now just getting KeyError 'WA'. I also added in () to state.abbrev because that needs parenthesis

Comment: SOLUTION: I also had to initialize statearray[state.abbrev()]={} inside of the for loop. It was a combination of both.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define elements without defining their parents first. Try this code

```
# define object
statearray = {}

for state in mystates:

    # define state.abbrev array, and elements
    statearray[state.abbrev] = {
        'count': 0,
        'total score': 0,
    }

    # this element references elements in statearray[state.abbrev]
    # so it must be defined after
    statearray['avg'] = statearray[state.abbrev()]['count']/statearray[state.abbrev()]['total score']
```